# TS library using react-router with support for both v5 and v6 throws Webpack error - export was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: typescript, webpack, react-router-dom, vite

I am building a library that uses React-Router. It assumes there is Router Provider on top and uses some hooks from `react-router-dom` package.
As such, `react-router-dom` library is added to `peerDependencies` in the library `package.json`.

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "react-router-dom": ">=5"
},
```

Now, as you can see, I would like to support multiple versions of react-router-dom, hence >=5.

To achieve that, in the code itself I am doing the following:

```js
import * as RR from 'react-router-dom';

export function useNavigate() {
  const location = RR.useLocation();

  // v6
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const navigateV6 = RR.useNavigate && RR.useNavigate();

  // v5
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const history = RR.useHistory && RR.useHistory();

  return navigateV6 || history.replace;
}
```

I am using Vite to build the lib using following config:

```js
build: {
  lib: {
    formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
  },
  rollupOptions: {
    // External packages that should not be bundled into your library.
    external: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react/jsx-runtime',
      'react-router-dom',
    ],
  },
},
```

CJS and ES bundles are exported through package.json `exports` fields:

```json
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "import": "./index.mjs",
    "require": "./index.js"
  }
},
```

## The Issue

"Vite-based" consumers can import and use the library just fine with either v5 or v6 of `react-router-dom`.

Webpack consumers though (using swc-loader) throw the following error:

> ERROR in ../../.yalc/@foo/test/index.mjs 18759:150-163 export
> 'useHistory' (imported as 'Zt') was not found in 'react-router-dom'
> (possible exports: ...

*using Yalc to test the package in consumers

What's wrong?

Comment: FWIW it's my very humble opinion that there are just too many breaking changes between React-Router v5 and v6 that it doesn't make sense to try and support both. For example, v5 `useHistory` returns a `history` object that has methods on it, e.g. `history.push`, `history.replace`, etc, while v6's `useNavigate` hook returns a `navigate` function, e.g. `navigate("...")` and `navigate("...", { replace: true })`. How would you differentiate these in whatever is returned?

Comment: I agree, it's just that we know for sure that we'll have consumers with v5 and v6.
For now I have removed dependency on react-router-dom altogether and reimplemented/rewrote a custom useNavigate() hook with native metods. Will wait for other replies and if not will post the solution as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Using a custom navigation solution seems like a more optimal/viable solution in my opinion. I will follow your post to see what you've created. Cheers.